# Python Coverage - Analyze only project files

Tags: python, coverage.py

I'm using [coverage](https://pypi.org/project/coverage/) module in python to check the code coverage. However, while running 'coverage report', the module is analyzing unwanted files shown below other than the project files.

[image: covering unwanted files]

**How can I remove unwanted files from executing in coverage report?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The simplest way is to use `--source=.` so that it will only consider files in the current directory.

Comment: Just wanted to add a complete example: `coverage run --source={{./MYDIR}} -m unittest discover -s tests/`

Answer (score 2):

You should use `--omit` flag to exclude the unwanted files. 
The RegEx is allowed to use. Eg.: `coverage run --omit "*/app/*,*__init__*,*_ut.py"`
You can see more details: https://coverage.readthedocs.io/en/v4.5.x/source.html